# Querying a table several times over querying the table once in a tmp table and querying that subset

Tags: database-optimization

I have a stored proc which queries this one table (have clustered index on it) several times to get the count and sum of various fields in that table. I am thinking of ways to optimize this stored proc. Would querying that table once on its primary key and putting the results in a tmp table and working on that tmp table to get the count and sum of various fields work better OVER querying the original table again and again to get the count and sum?

Comment: Why don't you try it out?